# What is this batch command doing? SET "MIBDIRS=%MIBDIRS:\=/%"

Tags: batch-file, special-characters, variable-assignment

What's going on here?

```
SET "MIBDIRS=%MIBDIRS:\=/%"
```

I thought I understood how `SET` worked, i.e. `SET "NAME=VALUE"`. I don't understand what the `:\=/` part of this expression means, and as you might imagine I've had no luck using a search engine.

---

For context, the preceding line of code was `SET "MIBDIRS=%~dp0php\extras\mibs"`.

Comment: I now have a sneaking suspicion that this might be regex.

Comment: Possibly a regex operation to replace back-slashes with forward-slashes?

Comment: no regex. It's substring replacing. See `set /?`. `%var:str1=str2%` replaces str1 with str2. Try `set var=hello world"` and `echo %var:l=x%`

Comment: also see [ss64](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: @Stephan Much appreciated friend.

Comment: I would have typed `set /?` before posting.